# How can I tell NHibernate to cache all instances of one class in a collection on AppStartUp?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, caching

Let's say I have a table "Countries" and I want to set NHibernate to load all its instances on the Application start-up and store all Country instances in a CountryCollection or a List.

Can I achieve this just by doing some configuration setting or I still need some coding to be implemented manually for loading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use its [2nd level cache](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/02/09/quickly-setting-up-and-using-nhibernate-s-second-level-cache.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should just enable 2nd level caching (and query cache if necessary). Then configure your mappings accordingly, and the first time the countries are fetched, they will be put in your cache. You don't need to do this in app_start.